# Commerce Product is not visible for anonymous user in search result

Tags: 7, commerce, search

I am using apachesolr, apachesolr_commerce, apachesolr_autocomplete for search functionality in drupal 7.
Commerce Product is not visible for anonymous user in search result but when loggedin Commerce Product results are including into search results.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Got solutions to Disable Apache Solr Access module and than search works fine for other users as well.
Thank you.